# How to React native ios build problem in xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcodebuild

I am creating a build for ios but getting problem

Error detail

> unable to find build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Developement:

Comment: Please share screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps

- Removing all account information from Xcode and quitting Xcode.
- Open Keychain Access and delete all my certificates, as well as all Apple root and intermediate certificates.
- Manually reinstall all Apple root and intermediate certificates.
- Relaunch Xcode and open Preferences > Accounts. Sign in to dev account, and select Download Manual Profiles.